# Need a secure way to bypass License check condition in a public method

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have two products A and B. A is a paid tool while B is a free tool. B uses the some dll of A. Now i have a method say

```
 public void licenseCheck(bool test){....}
```

this method contains a condition which gives alert "get license" if you dont have one. Now from one of the class of Product B i have to call licenseCheck method for some reason and since B is free and you dont need a license for it, it still gives "get license" Error.

I tried i changed the signature of the method

```
licenseCheck( bool test, bool byPasslicense = false)
```

and use the byPasslicense variable to bypass the condition of license checking. I gave default value to it because this method is used at many places.
This approach has some security issues as these dlls are used for many other paid products where licensing is required. some one can just call this method and pass "true" value to byPasslicense argument of  licenseCheck method. I dont want that. I just want it to bypass for  product B

*Note:
this is a completed project and I cant just change the whole method, i just have to bypass the condition responsible for license checking in the licenseCheck method.*

Comment: What is the reason you refer to here: "Now from one of the class of Product B i have to call licenseCheck method for some reason" ?? That may be the source of your problem. IF B is free, why are you forced to bother with a licence check ? Maybe you got a "free" licence you should use ?

Comment: So.... you have an entire method that seems to be devoted to license checking. You're calling it from somewhere else, but in a circumstance where you don't actually want the license to be checked... and you are apparently able to edit that call site... so why does it still need to call the function at all?

Comment: *Why* do you need to check the license from an assembly that doesn't require a license? You are specifically calling the method that has 1 job, and that is to check the license, and yet you want to *not* check the license? Please clarify why you need to do this.

Comment: Hi I am sorry. I mixed up some details. The method is used to connect to a particular sharepoint site and the details of it are then fetched. So it performs license check when u try to connect to a site. So in short, in all my products A or B, i need to try connect to a sharepoint site. When I connect to site using A it should perform license check and when i use B it shouldnt. Hope that helps

Comment: Sounds like a bad design to me where callers can dictate whether to perform a licence check or not.  Your problem is essentially that of **SharePoint authorization** so why don't you just use the credentials of the calling _product_ in order to determine whether to perform the license check or not

Comment: Thanks every one, It seems will have to change the architecture of the method. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have broken the **S** in the **SOLID** principles, in that the method `getLicense` does more than just checking the license, otherwise there would be no need to call it if you want it to *not* check the license.

So here is how you should solve this.

1. Split the `getLicense` method into two (at least) by extracting a portion of it into a new method. Leave the part that actually checks the license in the original method, and split the rest out to a new method. Make this new method `internal`.
2. Add this attribute to your A project: `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("B")]`
3. From B, call the new method instead of `getLicense`, thereby bypassing the license check.

Note that an `internal` method can only be accessed from within the same assembly, A in this instance, of from assemblies that A specifically says that internals are visible to, like B in this instance. 3rd party developers will not have direct access to that method.

---

### Example

Original class:

```
public class Dohickey
{
    public void getLicense(bool hasLicense)
    {
        if (!hasLicense) throw new Exception("Ewups");
        SetSomethingThatOtherCodeDependsOn();
        SetSomethingElseAsWell();
    }
}
```

after fix:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("B")]
// ...
public class Dohickey
{
    public void getLicense(bool hasLicense)
    {
        if (!hasLicense) throw new Exception("Ewups");
        SetThings();
    }

    internal void SetThings()
    {
        SetSomethingThatOtherCodeDependsOn();
        SetSomethingElseAsWell();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks will try that :)